# C# Winforms - Form Control Databinding - How to find source element

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding

Please bear with me if this question is stupid or has been asked before. I understand how to databind a form control to a datasource. I would like now to reverse and retrieve the data source element for a specific control. 
Example for a textbox:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.table1BindingSource, "ContactID", true));
```

How can I retrieve the result "ContactID" for textBox1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one Binding added to the DataBindings of Textbox then you can get the datamember value of the binding as following.

```
var binding = textBox1.DataBindings[0];
var member =  binding.BindingMemberInfo.BindingMember;

MessageBox.Show(member);
```

This should get you the value which are looking for.

Comment: No worries... I am glad that the issue is resolved. MSDN is a very good friend.